# not able to move forward from one jsf page to another

Tags: jsf

I am trying to build a simple jsf application in which i take user id and name as parameter and trying to display on another page with the help of ManagedBean but so far i haven't succeeded and also the console is showing no error/exception, below are the list of files i'am using.

**AddUser.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Add New User Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="ID"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{userBean.id}" required="true">
                <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.addUser}"
                value="Add Customer"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**ManagedBean**  (UserBean)

```
package com.sapient.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserBean implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    //Action method to add user
    public String addUser() {
        return "success";
    }  
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ListUser**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>List of Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="User #{userBean.name} is added successfully.">
        </h:outputText>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

**FacesConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>userBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.sapient.bean.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>AddUser</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/AddUser.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/ListUser.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Please help, any word of advice will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your main problem? Unable to move to `ListUser.jsp` OR `#{userBean.name}` is not showing on your `ListUser.jsp` page

Comment: unable to move to ListUser.jsp page

Comment: Please don't tag JSF 1.x questions with `[jsf-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic part of your code present in `AddUser.jsp`

```
   <h:inputText value="#{userBean.id}" required="true">
                <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500"/>
            </h:inputText>
```

As here you placed a `required="true"` in `<h:inputText../>` and I am damn sure that you are not giving the value in id field and you were just submitting the form by giving only `name`.So thats why your form is not submitting
**Solution:** 
Now you have two solutions
**1)** Don't change even a single word in code and just give value in `id` textfield.(Don't think that `0`) which you are seeing in `id` field as a default is a value which will pass the required field scenario 
**2)** Remove tha `required="true"` part form here `<h:inputText value="#{userBean.id}" required="true">` and you will see it running

Comment: hey, the problem still persist, firstly i was giving value to id other than 0 but it wasn't working, then i removed required="true" as you said but its still not working.  Please Help